# how to intercept that the update of window to the windows driver level?

Tags: windows, hook, kernel, gdi

how to intercept that the update of window to the windows driver level?

---windows update
 | 
 --user32.dll
  |
  ---ntdll.dll
------------------------------  (intercept point).
    | 
    ----kernel(win32.sys, etc...)

i want to intercept all the update of windows (gdi and ddraw update), then how to implement it?
i have one suggestion is that i hook gdi update api and ddraw update api separately. but i dot hook gdi update api, i have hook BitBlt, BeginPaint and GetDC, but i can't protect the windows updating.

how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question shows a fundamental misunderstanding about how updating windows and DWM work. What are you trying to accomplish at a high level? What user feature would you need to do this?

Comment: sorry, i want to intercept windows updating at application level, then the desktop don't updating again. this is my goal. the windows updating contain all the desktop windows updating, for example: administrator user, then in the desktop there are ie, media player etc.

Comment: But *why* do you want to do that?

Comment: the hook is global hook at desktop, api hook, this api contain BitBlt, GetDC, BeginPaint, i hook the system api and instead of my special function. but i can't intercept the window updating.